# Outlook Add-In issue when removing Roaming Settings from FunctionFile

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-js

I am having an issue with the use of the Roaming Settings with an Add-In that I've been working on.

We use the roaming settings to store the URL that the user will be making API calls to.  The manifest of the Add-In makes use of a Menu control so it provides two options.  One loads the add-in itself and the other is some javascript to clear the Roaming Settings.

```
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
}

function signOut(event) {
    Office.context.roamingSettings.remove('domain_url');
    Office.context.roamingSettings.saveAsync(() => {
        event.completed();
    }); 
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if I load the add-in and keep it open and then use the remove Roaming Settings Option from the other menu item then the roaming settings don't appear to be removed until I close the Add-In and open it again.

The loaded Add-In will still be able to get those Roaming Settings by calling:

```
return <T>Office.context.roamingSettings.get(name);
```

and will continue to be able to until I close the Add-In.

Does anyone know why these get calls are still providing results even though the Roaming Settings have been cleared and why it's only until I close the Add-In and re-open it that the get call above doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a quote from MS doc:

> Important: The RoamingSettings object is initialized from the
>   persisted storage only when the add-in is first loaded. For task
>   panes, this means that it is only initialized when the task pane first
>   opens. If the task pane navigates to another page or reloads the
>   current page, the in-memory object is reset to its initial values,
>   even if your add-in has persisted changes. The persisted changes will
>   not be available until the task pane is closed and reopened.